# Bar chart with sample values marked in x-axis? (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

I'm creating a density histogram using bar().  The Y-vector holds my sample data, and I create the bar graph using the following code:

```
            [nelements, centers] = hist(Y,(-9.5:1:7.5));
            bar(centers,nelements/numSamples,'hist')
            axis([-10 8 0 .33])
```

How would I go about placing a green 'X' along the x-axis of the bar chart if that value exists in Y?  (Even better would be if a dot-plot could be created along the x-axis instead, so duplicate values aren't blocking each other).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "that value exists in Y" you mean that the respective histogram count for that bin is larger than zero, then this should work:

```
ind = find(nelements > 0);
hold all
plot(centers(ind), 0, 'xg')
```

If by "dot-plot" you mean a one-dimensional scatter plot, this does it:

```
hold all
plot(Y, 0, 'xg')
```

In both cases the green 'X's are located on the x-axis, but it might look better if you put them slightly below. In the latter case e.g.:

```
yl = ylim;
yl(1) = -0.1 * diff(yl);
hold all
plot(Y, -0.05 * diff(yl), 'xg')
ylim(yl)
```